# Use bash instead of tcsh for non-interactive shells

Tags: bash, shell, tcsh

I have an environment similar to the one in this question: [Different shells for interactive and non-interactive work](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/67789/different-shells-for-interactive-and-non-interactive-work)

I'm currently stuck with tcsh as my "official" default shell. For interactive shells, I essentially `exec /bin/bash` from my `~/.login` file.

Is there any way to have bash be the shell for non-interactive shells?  Ie, if I do `ssh myserver env` it prints out that the shell is `/bin/tcsh`. I was looking at `~/.cshrc` and I see *where* I could put something in there to do this, but I don't know *what* to put in there. Or perhaps there is a different place to put something like this?

Currently if I `exec /bin/bash` from `~/.cshrc` for non-interactive shells, the above ssh command will hang (presumably because it's trying to exec an interactive shell from the non-interactive one).

Is it even possible to do what I want to do?

Comment: Are you asking specifically about the shell used by `ssh`, or are you _actually_ asking about non-interactive shells (i.e. scripts, which should be using the shell specified via their `#!`-line)?

Comment: @Kusalananda, isn't the shell started by SSH in e.g. `ssh somehost env' non-interactive too?

Comment: @ilkkachu It is (if you're running a command),  but the question title as about "non-interactive shells" and the question body about "the specific shell started by ssh".  These are two different things.  Affecting them (which shell is started) is done through different means. SSH always runs the user's login shell.  A script doesn't necessarily do that.

Comment: _Must_ you remain with `tcsh`? If not, try `chsh --shell /bin/bash`

Comment: Specifically, it would be the shell started by SSH. I hadn't thought about that vs all non-interactive shells. There are some great suggestions here and I'm going to give them a try and see.

Comment: I do have to use tcsh. My shell is not saved locally so chsh doesn't work. It's set on the LDAP server. I've tried changing it via the chsh.ldap script, but it didn't seem to take. I assume I don't have RW permissions, but I'd rather not have to go down that investigation path if I can avoid it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your remote machine is Linux, try adding this to your `~/.tcshrc`:

```
if ($?SSH_CONNECTION && $shlvl == 1) then
    set sh = /bin/bash
    set cmdline = "`tr '\0\n' '\n\1' </proc/$$/cmdline`"
    if ($#cmdline > 2) then
        exec $sh -c 'exec "$0" -c "$(printf %s "$1" | tr "\1" "\n")"' $sh $cmdline[3]:q
    endif
endif
```

When you call `ssh user@host cmd`, what the ssh server basically does is calling the login shell of `user` with `-c` and `cmd` passed to it as arguments. If you call just `exec /bin/bash` from your `~/.cshrc`, bash will be called without arguments and will expect to read commands from its stdin, which means that `ssh user@host cmd` will appear to "hang" until you press Ctrl-C or Ctrl-D.

The kludge above tries to get the `cmd` argument from `/proc/<pid>/cmdline` and then call your choice shell (`/bin/bash`) in the same way, with `-c` and `cmd` passed to it as arguments. **It assumes that no ascii `\1` control character (Ctrl-A) is present in `cmd`**. That and most of the complications are from trying to preserve newlines in `cmd`, and I'm not at all sure I got that shit right ;-)

Improvements (and simplifications!) welcome.

Comment: In csh ```set a="`printf 'X\n\nY'`"``` works differently from the bourne shell: it splits on newlines, setting `$a[1]` to `X` and `$a[2]` to `Y`. If you have a better idea how to get rid those `tr`s and the extra exec, a testcase would be (assuming that the login shell of `user` is (t)csh, and the local shell supports `$'...'`): `ssh user@host $'echo $0; cat <<EOT\na   b\n\n\nc\nEOT\n'` should preserve both the spaces and the newlines exactly, as if her login shell were bash.

Comment: Ah, ok. No, I just wondered why that was required, since I'm not that familiar with csh.

Comment: Thank you Kusalananda, Uncle Billy, and Stéphane Chazelas.  Once I realized the _real_ question was about the SSH shell and with Stéphane's SSH magic plus Uncle Billy's .cshrc logic I was able to accomplish my goal. Thank you all very much.  (I really wish I could accept both answers, since they were both extremely useful.)

Answer (score 1):

You could add to your `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`:

```
command="setenv SHELL \"`which bash\"`; if ($?SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND) eval 'exec bash -c $SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND:q'; exec bash -l" your-pub-key-here
```

To force that command line, interpreted by your login shell (`tcsh`) to be run instead of the requested command when you ssh in with that key. If passed a command line, it will be available in the `$SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND` env var, and we tell `bash` to execute it, if not, we just start bash as a login shell.

We set `$SHELL` to the path of `bash` to tell applications started within the ssh session that `bash` is your preferred shell instead of tcsh your login shell.

Comment: I guess that you could just set `command="" ssh-rsa ...` in `~/.authorized_keys` and move all that `SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND` logic to `~/.cshrc`.